# How to decide which interface will putty bind the port forwarding?

Tags: ssh, putty, tunnel

My computer has two interfaces connected to the same router.

One of the interfaces will be used for VPNing and will loose access to real world, the other stays normal (will just have a higher metric).

When I use putty to configure tunnes, I'd like it to bind it's tunnels to the interface facing the real word. Is that possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Putty doesn't chose an interface.  It simply opens a port and lets the OS pick the path your routing table dictates.  If your connecting to an address which isn't local, it will use the default-route's interface.  if it's local to a specific network interface, it will use the interface.

You'll need to pay specific attention to the gateway used for the route, the route's metric, etc...

If you need more help with understanding your routing table, just let me know which OS, and post your routing table so I can reference it.